# Non interactive Azure App Web request in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, oauth-2.0, oauth, token

I have an Azure app named myApp. This app is a website on which you have to sign in with your Microsoft account.
I created a scope in this app named myscope.

What I want to do is make a web request (in powershell) to this website.

I managed to do it with the method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/auth-v2-user) by "manually" getting the code first and then the token and finally calling

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "myurl" -Headers  @{"authorization" = "Bearer $token"}
```

What I want to do now is exactly the same thing but in a fully **non-interactive** way. I mean without the need to log in manually. It can be with credentials, client secret or other ideas ...

Could someone explain to me the steps to do this?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This feels like you may need to look at the architecture, since you have 2 clients that need to get data.

**GETTING AN ACCESS TOKEN (AUTHENTICATING)**

If this sounds right then it would involve first registering two different entries in Azure AD:

- Website client uses Authorization Code Flow to authenticate users via Azure and get tokens
- Powershell client is not interactive so should probably use [Client Credentials Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

**USING AN ACCESS TOKEN (DATA ACCESS)**

The most standard setup would work like this:

- Website client sends access token to a Web API
- Powershell client sends access token to the same Web API

If the data access code is in the website itself then this may not work, since the web app is not designed to work for the Powershell client, and is likely to require a secure cookie that Powershell cannot provide.

**FIRST STEPS**

I would focus on the data the Powershell client needs and design how it should work if done properly. Can this be factored out into a small API as above?

If this is expensive then maybe a tactical solution could be used, such as a new website endpoint that accepts tokens and is only called from Powershell.